# Is it possible for a geodesic to intersect two distinct geodesics in the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Considering the hyperbolic plane, is it possible for a geodesic to intersect orthogonally two other, distinct geodesics $L, L'$ that do not intersect with each other at $\infty?$ (that is, $L,L'$ do not intersect with each other at infinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Poincaré disk model, let $L_0$ be the hyperbolic set corresponding to the Euclidean line $y=0$, and let $L$ and $L'$ be the hyperbolic sets corresponding to the Euclidean circles $(x-\sec \theta)^2+y^2=\tan^2 \theta$, $(x+\sec \theta)^2+y^2=\tan^2 \theta$ for some $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$. Then $L$ has a radius which is tangent to the unit circle at the point $(\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$, so $L$ is a hyperbolic line, and similarly with $L'$. These lines do not intersect, even at infinity, because they are separated by the line $x=0$. But $L_0$ is perpendicular to both.

[Here's](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/t6r8rke7) a GeoGebra link which hopefully helps illustrate all of this.

(In general, if $L,L'$ are two any non-intersecting geodesics, there will be points $p\in L$ and $q \in L'$ at which that the distance between $L$ and $L'$ is minimized. The line $pq$ is then orthogonal to both $L$ and $L'$.)

Comment: Hi, Micah. And, Im assuming that for the more general case with regards to $L_0,$ one can consider the isometry $\phi$ which turns $L_0$ into the vertical line? Since isometries preserve distances and angles, $L$ will still intersect orthogonally with $L_0.$ Then, we can apply your reasoning to find the third geodesic, and apply $\phi^{-1}?$

Comment: Hey, Micah. Could you address a few questions? You first say $L$ is a hyperbolic set corresponding to  Euclidean circle, then you say $L$ is a hyperbolic line. How is this possible? (I'm sure it is - I would just like to understand). Second, you say the radius is perpendicular to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta):$ is that the radius radiating from the center? Would the second circle have a radius target to another point? It doesn't seem like it has a radius target to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta).$

Comment: Did you meant $y = 0$ when you wrote $x = 0?$ Maybe Im not completely understanding what these hyperbolic lines look like.

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud: The lines in the Poincaré disk model of the hyperbolic plane are 1) line segments through the origin, or 2) circular segments which intersect the bounding circle of the model perpendicularly. In my case $L_0$ is of type 1) and $L,L'$ are of type 2). I added a link to a GeoGebra picture which will hopefully help illustrate all this.

Comment: The lines $L,L'$ intersect the line $y=0$ (which contains the segment $L_0$) but are separated by the line $x=0$ (which is why they do not intersect each other).

Answer (score 1):

In fact this *always* happens.

For any geodesic $M$, and for any distinct points $p \ne p' \in M$, if we let $L,L'$ denote the unique geodesics that meet $M$ orthogonally at the points $p,p'$ respectively, then the geodesics $L$ and $L'$ do not intersect with each other at infinity (nor finitely for that matter).

One way to see this is to work in the upper half plane model, where $M$ is the geodesic $x=0$. Each of $L,L'$ is a Euclidean semicircle hitting $x=0$ orthogonally, the first at $p = (0,y)$ and the second at $p'=(0,y')$, where $y,y' > 0$ and $y \ne y'$ by assumption. The Euclidean radii of these circles are $y,y'$. The points at infinity of $L$ are $(y,0)$, $(-y,0)$ and the points at infinity of $L'$ are $(y',0),(-y',0)$.